# How to use Accept() for multiple connections

Tags: c, http

I'm trying to send *http* response to the browser at my code (I use virtual machine of linux), when I debug my code I can tell that after one request and response, the `accpet()` function doesn't wait and continue the procedure even if I did close the socket-fd.

Does anyone have any idea why is this happening?

Here is my code:

```
while(1){  // infinite loop for requests

        if (( user_socket = accept(fsockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addrf,          // wait for a request from customer and accept new socket
                       (socklen_t*)&addrlenf))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
        while(flag_rec!=1){
            if(recv(user_socket, customer_reply , BUFSIZE , 0) < 0)                  // get the request from customer
    {
        puts("recv failed my man");  // in case of failing
    }
        for(int i=0; i<BUFSIZE;i++){
            if(customer_reply[i]=='\r'&&customer_reply[i+1]=='\n'&&customer_reply[i+2]=='\r'&&customer_reply[i+3]=='\n'){ //checking if there is \r\n\r\n
                customer_reply[i+4]='\0';
                customer_reply_size=i+4;
                flag_rec=1;  // it means we received the full http request
                break;
            }

        }
    


        }
        flag_rec=0;
        if(send(serv_socket,customer_reply,customer_reply_size,0)<0){      // sending the http request to the servers
            puts("send failed"); // in case of failing
        }
        while(flag_rec!=1){
        if(recv(serv_socket,server_reply,BUFSIZE,0)<0){                    // get the answer message from the servers
            puts("recv failed mann");  // in case of failing
        }
        for(int i=0; i<BUFSIZE;i++){
            if(server_reply[i]=='\r'&&server_reply[i+1]=='\n'&&server_reply[i+2]=='\r'&&server_reply[i+3]=='\n'&&server_reply[i+4]=='\0'){ //checking if there is \r\n\r\n
                server_reply[i+4]='\0';
                server_reply_size=i+4;
                flag_rec=1;  // it means we received the full http request
                break;
               
            }

        }
        }
        flag_rec=0;
        if(send(user_socket,server_reply,server_reply_size,0)<0){
            puts("send failed"); // in case of failing
        }
        close(user_socket);  // closing the socket after the response
        
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Every `accept` returns a new socket (`user_socket` as it's called in your program). You need to store that somewhere together with the other `user_socket`s you've gotten from earlier `accept` calls.

Comment: ok,but why i need to store it with other user_socket from earlier accept call if i dont need it anymore,i just need a new user_socket?

Comment: So, it makes a new successful `accept` call without you making more than one connection attempt?

Comment: @EVIFELDI quick question for you, what are you initializing `flag_rec` to before your `while` loop?

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<BUFSIZE;i++){` <<-- BUFSIZE is not the correct limit. `recv()` returns a value. Use it!

Comment: Your MCV example might be Minimal, but it is not Complete, so it precludes Verifiability.

Comment: flag_rec is used to make sure i finished receive the reques.. when i finished i put the flag=1 and after i finish take care of the request and sends it i bring it back to the first value so other request can do the same

Comment: @EVIFELDI yes I see that but it is used at `while(flag_rec!=1)` and I don't know how that statement evaluates because I don't know how you've initialized it.

Comment: When i did an array of ints to use for user_socket it still makes the same problem - when i arrive to the second call of accept() it doesnt wait and continue automatically.why it doesnt stops on accept()?? i need it to wait on accept till the second call from browser arrived

Comment: i dont think that the problem is that user_socket is not an fixed array or something like this.. because i tried to do that and again,first time it wait for a request and second time it continue without waiting to a request.. maybe it is related to some flag or something that need to move to accept()?

Comment: Take a look at the manual pages for `select()` or `poll()`. You should also read the manual pages for `recv()` or `read()`, because your program fragment contains many rather trivial errors.

Comment: hi can you tell me where is my trivial errors? i understand about the BUFSIZE but what else contains a trivial error in your opinion?

Comment: @EVIFELDI there's too many unknowns that are preventing us from helping you further unfortunately. For example, I asked for more information `flag_rec` but you didn't provide so there's nothing else I can do to help you out. Good luck though.

Comment: `understand about the BUFSIZE ` Do you? improve the program and ask another question. Just one question.